# Can I use a second OpenGL context to render a UI on top of a 3D scene?

Tags: opengl, sdl-2

Is it possible to draw to the same OpenGL viewport using more than one OpenGL context, in such a way that each context has its own, completely separate rendering state?

My use case would be a 3D scene on top of which I would like to render my UI. The UI uses of course settings that are very different from the 3D scene - no projection for a start, and then the 3D scene uses legacy OpenGL whereas the UI has a custom shader program.

So, my idea would be to have each rendering task (3D scene and UI) use its own OpenGL context, which each could configure according to its own needs, once, at window initialization time. At rendering time, each task would then simply select its own rendering context, avoiding the need to waste time re-configuring a single context.

I had a try at this right now, but got a blank screen - that may of course be due to a mistake in my code, but before investing more time into this, I'd like to know whether this is an idea worth pursuing, or one that goes against the grain of OpenGL.

(I'm working with SDL2 under Windows 10, using GLEW, and compiling for 32-bit using Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: ... why would you want to do this? Why not simply use one rendering context, changing the rendering state to whatever is appropriate for the rendering operation you want to do?

Comment: @NicolBolas One reason would be to switch between states faster, the other to keep the states separate and independent of each other. The question is whether OpenGL contexts are intended to work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an idea worth pursuing. For the following reasons:

> One reason would be to switch between states faster

This will not switch states faster. At least, not in terms of real-world performance. Switching rendering contexts is a *very* heavyweight operation. Changing every piece of a context's state would still be *faster* than doing a full context switch.

Oh, I'm sure it's faster *for you to write*. But it won't make your actual program faster.

> the other to keep the states separate and independent of each other

You can do that easily enough by simply making sure to have these distinct rendering operations set the state they rely on at the beginning of their operations. This also has the effect of making sure that *you know* what state your operations are relying on.

Each operation can have its own separate objects: VAOs, buffers, textures, programs, even framebuffers. That, plus making sure to change the important global state when needed, is all you need to keep those two operations separate.

Comment: Is there a reason why switching contexts is so heavy-weight? I'm aware of the need to flush pipelines, but in many cases, including this one, that very probably happens anyway because of glUseProgram(). It would be nice to have a way to composite rendering without having to manage all the state manually. "Faster to write" wasn't my primary goal.

Comment: @JPNotADragon: "*I'm aware of the need to flush pipelines*" Does there need to be more of a reason than that? Changing OpenGL state does not cause a pipeline flush. Reading OpenGL state, or calling `glFlush` or `glFinish` causes a pipeline flush.

Answer (score 0):

With one context, cn each frame, after you render the 3D scene, disable `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, render the 2D part, then enable it again.

With more than 1 context you should probably be rendering to a FBO then render UI on top of that.

Comment: That's not the problem I had - my 3D scene would not render. Like I said, that could be because of a mistake I made, then again it did render before I introduced the second context.

Comment: My idea of having several contexts was intended to avoid having to manually set states each time before rendering - a FBO would very probably be way more time-consuming than that.

Comment: @JPNotADragon: I would be curious to know what your basis is for assuming that FBO changes are slower than a rendering context switch. Just because one method involves more function calls doesn't mean its slower.

Comment: @nicolbolas: the FBO has to be copied to the output buffer at some point; that will not only make rendering somewhat slower, but increase video memory consumption two-fold.